# Property passed to Invoke-Command changes type from IDictionary to HashTable

Tags: powershell, dictionary, hashtable, psobject, powershell-v5.1

I've been getting an error running `Invoke-Command` where the script block takes a parameter of type dictionary:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'dictionary'.
>   Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type
>   "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type
>   "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]".
>   At line:7 char:1
>   + Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ArgumentList $dictionary -ScriptBlock ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [], ParameterBindin...mationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost

After a lot of digging I was able to reduce the script to the the MVP below to show the root of this issue:

```powershell
[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string, string]]$dictionary = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]' 
$dictionary.Add('one', 'hello')
$dictionary.Add('two', 'world')
Write-Verbose "Main Script $($dictionary.GetType().FullName)" -Verbose #outputs: VERBOSE: Before System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ArgumentList $dictionary -ScriptBlock {
    Param (
        #[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string, string]] #if I leave this in I get a conversion error
        $dictionary
    )
    Write-Verbose "Function before $($dictionary.GetType().FullName)" -Verbose #outputs: VERBOSE: After System.Collections.Hashtable
    function Poc {} #this line seems to cause the `$dictionary` to become a HashTable
    Write-Verbose "Function after $($dictionary.GetType().FullName)" -Verbose #outputs: VERBOSE: After System.Collections.Hashtable

}
```

It seems that if the script block for `Invoke-Command` includes any inline functions then the parameter is automatically converted to a `HashTable`; whilst if the script block doesn't contain any nested function definitions the parameter is left as a `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string, string]`.

Am I misusing this feature / is there a common workaround?  Or is this a just a bug in PowerShell?

Comment: Oh wow. I always thought this is a core PS problem. But never thought a bug. mkelement0 answers that neatly and my recommendation is to Stock this question permanently. Drawing moderator attention to have this question frozen. This is one of the core PS flaws which can help all. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing a ***by-design limitation*  of the XML-based *serialization infrastructure* that underlies PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote)** (which is what `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` is based on):

- **Objects of types that implement the [`IDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface are deserialized as *only one of two - non-generic - types*** (even though the original, full type name is *recorded* in the serialization data), namely  as either:

  - In *PowerShell 7.3.0 and above only* (see below), **`[ordered]` hashtables ([`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary))** *if and only if* that precise type was used as input.<sup>[2]</sup>
  - **`[hashtable]` ([`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable))** for *all other dictionary types*, including *generic* types such as `[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string, string]]` in your case; both the keys and values of this type `[object]`-typed.

Such **potential *loss of type fidelity*** is inherent in PowerShell's remoting, because **only a limited set of *well-known types* are faithfully deserialized**, because the idea is to make remoting work across both different PowerShell versions and nowadays between the two PowerShell *editions*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for a systematic overview of PowerShell's serialization.

For **basic usage of dictionary types, a loss of type fidelity shouldn't matter, however**: Thanks to the `IDictionary` interface, enumeration, entry access and getting the entry count all work the same.

However, in **PowerShell 7.2.x and below**, including in **Windows PowerShell**, **`[ordered]` hashtables were incorrectly deserialized as *unordered* `[hashtable]`s**, which notably lost the original ordering of their entries and prevented entry access by *positional* index on the deserialized object.

- See [GitHub issue #2861](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2861#issuecomment-318525355) for the original bug report..
- As noted, this **problem has been fixed in v7.3.0** (see [GitHub PR #15545](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/15545)).

Comment: Excuse me if I am sounding noob, but I want to clear myself on this. What do you mean by non-generic hashtable? Are you only referring the order only?

Comment: @RanadipDutta:  Please see my update; the aspects of ordering vs. use of a generic type are unrelated. Both the unordered (`@{ ... }`) and the ordered (`[ordered] @{ ... }`) types that PowerShell supports are non-generic.
(And, surprisingly, there is currently no _generic_ ordered dictionary - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2629027/45375.)

Comment: Thanks @mklement0; that's much clearer than my first tweak; nice one :)